# Styleclass not being applied when the previous style class is added in FXML

Tags: class, button, styles, javafx, fxml

I assign styleclass of ToggleButton in FXML file as follows:

```
<ToggleButton fx:id="Button" styleClass="defaultStyle">
```

Later, in my code I change the style classes as follows:

```
@FXML private ToggleButton Button;
Button.getStyleClass().remove("defaultStyle");
Button.getStyleClass().add("newStyle");
```

The CSS file is defined as:

```
 .defaultStyle { -fx-background-color: black;}
 .newStyle { -fx-background-color: red;}
```

EDITED:
The new style is applied when done in the Controller, but the new style is not being applied when done somewhere else. When I debug, I see the correct style-class being added & removed to the button.

Anyone got a workaround for this problem? I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Style class removing and adding are working as expected. I guess your problem is the ToggleButton has not been injected correctly, it should be:

```
@FXML private ToggleButton Button;
...
Button.getStyleClass().remove("defaultStyle");
Button.getStyleClass().add("newStyle");
```

in the controller class. Note the capital b of "Button" since you have defined `fx:id="Button"` in FXML file. Also note that you don't need to instantiate the `ToggleButton Button` (like `new ToggleButton()`) yourself.

**EDIT:**
Here is code example for changing the styleclass. As I said it is working as expected. Compare it with yours.

Sample.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="somepackage.SampleController">
    <stylesheets>
        <String fx:value="somepackage/style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
        <ToggleButton layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="mybutton" styleClass="defaultStyle" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

SampleController.java:

```
package somepackage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton mybutton;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("before :" + mybutton.getStyleClass());
        mybutton.getStyleClass().remove("defaultStyle");
        mybutton.getStyleClass().add("newStyle");
        System.out.println("after  :" + mybutton.getStyleClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

MainDemo.java:

```
package somepackage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("version: " + com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The css file includes selectors of yours.

Comment: Here, 'button' is defined as "@FXML private ToggleButton button;" I am not recreating the button instance. I don't see the styles being applied to the ToggleButton in the GUI. (I have edited my previous post to include this correction)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it is only done when the controller does it.

Use the FXMLLoader to load your controller. then you change the StyleClass to the newStyle.